# Books and sources concerning $G$-spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topological-groups

A $G$-space is (generally) a topological space $X$ equipped with a continuous action by a topological group $G$. I mean generally because, I've never studied before $G$-spaces and after I read a couple of papers involving them, I've been looking for the exact definition on the internet but there are different conditions like:

- $G$ is just a group;
- the action is not necessarily continuous;
- $X$ is Hausdorff (I think this is because the author of the document was working with Hausdorff spaces).

So my request is regarding for books concerning the definition of a $G$-space in the most generally sense and, why not, the precedence of its nature.

Comment: The case where the action is not demanded continuous is actually a special case, somehow, of a G-space; it's a G-space where G is demanded discrete. Anyway, try tom Dieck's book on tranaformation groups.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks.

Comment: @MikeMiller In which part is defined a G-space in that book? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: Page 2. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Topological Groups And Related Structures" by Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko (the definition is right after Example $10.2.6$).

See also "Topological Groups" by Dikranjan, Prodanov and Stoyanov (after Lemma $7.6.6$).

Comment: Thanks! Btw, in the second reference 7.6.6 is not a lemma but a proposition.